# Is flush() call necessary when using try-with-resources

Tags: java, try-with-resources

Will `try-with-resources` call `flush()` implicitly?

If it does, in the following code snippet, `bw.flush()` can be safely removed?

```
static void printToFile1(String text, File file) {
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
        bw.write(text);
        bw.flush();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // handle ex
    }
}
```

ps.
I don't see any description about it in official document:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html

Comment: no. but `close()` usually does flushing anyway.

Comment: 5 answers so far, *all* quoting the javadoc. Guess that's a sign to *read the doc*.

Comment: @ZhongYu Does the word `usually` works as anyone expected?

Comment: @Andreas all those answers quote the Javadoc of some Writer class. Thus they all answer only the second, follow-up question of the OP. Only one answer _addresses_ the first, more general question (but does not really answer it, either).

Comment: @Qw3ry What do you mean? They all answer it, by quoting the `Writer` javadoc saying that closing auto-flushes for you. The question is *entirely* about `Writer`, because it is the Writer class, not the (Auto)Closeable interface, that *declares* the **`flush()`** method that is the primary topic of the question, so there is no "more general" answer to the question.

Comment: @Andreas it's true that (Auto)Closeable doesn't declare `flush()`, but actually it's not `Writer` that declares it either. The [`Writer`-Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#flush()) of `flush()` explicitely refers to the declaration in `Flushable`. Writer only _overrides_ `flush()`. Because `Flushable` does not extend (Auto)Closeable, its declaration cannot say anything on implementions of `close()`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[`Closeable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) and [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) are general-purpose interfaces that do not know anything about flushing. So you can't find any information about it in their documentation - except some words about *releasing resources*.

A [`Writer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) on the other hand is a more specific-purpose abstract class that now knows something about flushing. Some excerpt of the documentation for the method [`Writer.close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#close--):

> Closes the stream, *flushing it first*.

So - yes - when using a writer, a `close` will always also `flush`. This basically means that you have to consult the documentation of the concrete classes that you are using when trying to find out what closing really does.

Answer (score 11):

The resources are automatically closed when using [try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block. As part of this process it will also invoke flush automatically.

As mentioned in doc for [close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close%28%29) method of BufferedWriter:

> Closes the stream, flushing it first. Once the stream has been closed,
>   further write() or flush() invocations will cause an IOException to be
>   thrown.

Answer (score 5):

I really don't understand why other answers focus on the `BufferedWriter` not `try-with-resources`.

I, either, couldn't find any specification or mentions that the `try-with-resources` statements calls `flush()` on any objects of `Flushable`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3

Don't rely on any undocumented/unspecified behavior of vendor specific implementations.

```java
try (OutputStream o = open()) {
    //writeSome
    o.flush(); // won't hurt!
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Quoting javadoc of [BufferedWriter.close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close%28%29):

> Closes the stream, **flushing it first**.

Answer (score 4):

The minimum amount of code to be written in this case:

```
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out))) {
    bw.write("Test");
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Hence you don't need to call explicitly the [flush](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#flush--) method, as it will be called by the [close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close--) method, as explained in the javadoc:

> Closes the stream, flushing it first. Once the stream has been closed,
>   further write() or flush() invocations will cause an IOException to be
>   thrown. Closing a previously closed stream has no effect.

This behavior is inherited from the [Writer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) class, hence besides [BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) the same behavior is provided also by: [CharArrayWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/CharArrayWriter.html), [FilterWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FilterWriter.html), [OutputStreamWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html), [PipedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PipedWriter.html), [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html), [StringWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html).

This behavior is not provided in the documentation of the [tryWithResources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) or [AutoCloseable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) as the behavior is specific to the given implementation of [Writer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html). As [Writer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html)extends [Closeable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Closeable.html), it will call the [close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close--) method  when exiting the try {} block and the close method will first call 
[flush](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#flush--) as already mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

From the Javdocs:

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one
>   or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after
>   the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement
>   ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. Any
>   object that implements `java.lang.AutoCloseable`, which includes all
>   objects which implement `java.io.Closeable`, can be used as a
>   resource.

The `BufferedWriter.close()` explicitly stated that:

> Closes the stream, flushing it first. Once the stream has been closed, further write() or flush() invocations will cause an IOException to be thrown. Closing a previously closed stream has no effect.