# FileWriter - without try-with-resource data is not fully written to file

Tags: java, resources, filewriter, try-with-resources

I want to write 1 million lines to a text file.

When I use FileWriter without `try-with-resource` style(not releasing resources), I found it stops at around 998976 and so.

```
...
998968
998969
998970
998971
998972
998973
998974
998975
998976
9
```

```java
    @Test
    void writeTooLargeFileThisIsBad() throws IOException {
        File newFile = new File("src/test/resources/targets/large.csv");
        if (!newFile.exists()) newFile.createNewFile();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("src/test/resources/targets/large.csv", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++) {
            writer.write(String.valueOf(i));
            writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
        }
    }
```

But when I do with try with resource, it completes normally. (It reaches 999999)

Both very quick.

Why?

```java
    @Test
    void writeTooLargeFileThisIsGood() throws IOException {
        File newFile = new File("src/test/resources/targets/large.csv");
        if (!newFile.exists()) newFile.createNewFile();
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("src/test/resources/targets/large.csv", StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {

            for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++) {
                writer.write(String.valueOf(i));
                writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's probably because the writer doesn't get closed in the end, so the final lines of output may not be flushed and output to the file. Just a guess though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are not calling `close()` method on the `writer` instance - the writer has some buffer defined able to store quite big amount of unwritten data

When you are using `try-with-resource` approach the `close()` is being called automatically so every data is being flushed properly

---

Read more here:

- [BufferedWriter not writing everything to its output file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426142/bufferedwriter-not-writing-everything-to-its-output-file/13426160)
- [Is flush() call necessary when using try-with-resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32324492/is-flush-call-necessary-when-using-try-with-resources)